# Replace special characters from a String

Tags: java, string

im finding a problem when doing a replace special characters using the replaceAll method.

i have this piece of code:

```
public static String replaceSpecialCharacters(String cadena) {

   cadena = cadena.replaceAll("[âãáàä]", "a");
   cadena = cadena.replaceAll("[ÂÃÁÀÄ]", "A");
   cadena = cadena.replaceAll("[éèêë]", "e");
   cadena = cadena.replaceAll("[ÉÈÊË]", "E");
   cadena = cadena.trim();
   return cadena;
}
```

when a string like "Álamont" fot instance comes, the method returns right the string "Alamont", however this string returned in the replace is not the same than "Alamont", first if I see the count attribute of the string it says its "8" instead of "7"....and if I tri to do:

```
if (cadena.equalsIgnoreCase("Alamont")) {
    System.out.println("i've got ya!!");
}
```

it nevers goes in...im sure the problemas is in the replace character...can someone help me??

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: count or length?  those are two different things.  Also, I'm pretty sure "Alamont" will never equal "atico".

Comment: Which string do you compare with "atico"? And how you get this string?

Comment: "the method returns right the string "Alamont", however this string returned in the replace is not the same than "Alamont""

This doesn't even make sense. Are you getting what you're expecting from `replaceAll` or not? What are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry i meant if (cadena.equalsIgnoreCase("Alamont")), i've edited the post. I'm expecting to get Alamont after the replace. I'm getting Alamont from the replaceAll but it the equals returns false

Comment: I just ran `String c = "Álamont"; String cadena = replaceSpecialCharacters(c); if (cadena.equalsIgnoreCase("Alamont")) { System.out.println("i've got ya!!"); }` (forgive the lack of formatting in a comment!) and it works just fine - it prints "i've got ya!!". I think you need to provide more information with how you are invoking your method. Please provide a full block of code that illustrates the entire problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cleanup your question. It’s not clear, what you mean with “*the method returns right the string "Alamont", however this string returned in the replace is not the same than "Alamont"* ”, and it is not clear why you are surprised that the returned `String` might have a different length if you use `trim` or why you expect `"Alamont"` to be equal to `"atico"`.

---

However, removing accents and other diacritical marks in a `String` can be easier than performing dozens of replace operations and risking to forget one:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
…
s=Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}", "");
```

Comment: Thanks Holger, i was trying Normalizer.normalize(s, Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""); but i will try tomorrow with \p{Mn} and let you know if works

Comment: `Mn` means [non-spacing mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm) so `InCombiningDiacriticalMarks` will be more precise. But I don’t know whether it makes a difference for your use case. I’ll update my answer.

Comment: Well looks like s=Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}", ""); really solves most of the problems I was having. However for this particular case its not working, the field "cadena" comes from an xml file, and when encoding the "Á" from Álamont its removed and its now "A" removing the accent, however the length is 8 instead of 7 as it shoudl be since now the word has no accent

Comment: Your description is as confusing at it was the first time. If the `String` has 8 characters though there clearly are only seven visible characters (is that what you meant?) then there must be an invisible character. It should be easy to write a code looping through the characters of the `String` printing the `Unicode` numbers of each character to detect what invisible character is there. Once you spot it, I guess, the solution would be near.

Comment: thanks and sorry for the bad description. Yes there're only seven visible characters. The unicode char its supposed to be Á( U+00C1), however debugging I see it comes as Ã (U+00C3)

Comment: That doesn’t matter; it’s still one character. The question is what the undesired invisible character is.

Comment: I have this when i get the unicode to get the missing char: A\u81lamont , looks like the normalizer dont remove the \u81 (&lt;control&gt;)

Comment: *Now* I understand what the real problem is. You source string was `UTF-8` encoded but your import did use a wrong encoding to convert the bytes to characters. Therefore you see `Ã\x81lamont` as \xC3\x81 is the correct `UTF-8` sequence for Á. You should fix the importing code to use `UTF-8` for decoding.

Comment: but the enconding of the file is ISO-8859-1 not UTF-8, so im proccesing the source as ISO :S

Comment: Who says it is iso-latin-1? If someone claims it to be iso-latin-1 but writes \xC3\x81 for Á (s)he is wrong. Well, it could be possible that even the generation of the file is erroneous but now we are really far beyond the original question.

Comment: you're right, i give your reply as correct. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like your input values are using [combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). There's nothing wrong with this, but you should expect the String length to change.

There are ways to normalize your strings to use the non-combining version of the character ... but I forget.... there it is, [Normalization tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html) ... that link is causing my browser (firefox, in ie it works better) to slow down, but it is the real link!... maybe the [Normalizer JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) will be enough